# Google People API: null when listing connections

Tags: .net, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-people-api

When using [Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1), the people.connections.list method seems to work (no exceptions are thrown) but the returned object always have all its fields set to null. Here is the relevant code:

```cs
var scopes = new[] { PeopleServiceService.Scope.ContactsReadonly, PeopleServiceService.ScopeConstants.Contacts };
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("./my-secrets.json")
                                 .CreateScoped(scopes);
var service = new PeopleServiceService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
});

var req = service.People.Connections.List("people/me");
req.PageSize = 2000;
req.RequestMaskIncludeField = "person.names";
req.Fields = "connections,totalItems,nextSyncToken";

var res = await req.ExecuteAsync();
Console.WriteLine(res.Connections.Count); // <-- NullReferenceException
```

my-secrets.json is the secrets file downloaded from console.developers.google.com. It looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "",
  "token_uri": "",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
  "client_x509_cert_url": ""
}
```

Does someone know what I'm missing ?

Comment: Same issue here. I see the name, but the email address is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The PeopleService API requires a user credential, not a service credential.

In a locally installed app (e.g. a console app), use `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(...)` to get one of these.

The request must set `req.PersonFields` as described here: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list#query-parameters
E.g. `req.PersonFields = "emailAddresses";`

It is not necessary to set `req.Fields` or `req.RequestMaskIncludeField`.

Comment: Can a user crendential be used for a batch application ? From what I've understood I needed to use a service crendential to avoid prompting a login form to the user.

Comment: You should be able to interactively request a user-credential once, making sure you request "offline access". This will include a "refresh token" in the response, which allows you to request further user-credentials as you need. Note that the user can cancel this refresh token, and the refresh token can be cancelled for reasons beyond your control, so you must be prepared for it to fail. You'll then need to interactively request it again from the user.